# Xcodeにてフレームワークの管理方法

Tags: xcode8

いつもお世話になっております。

Xcodeに外部のフレームワークをインストールする時に以下があります。
Embedded Binaries
Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Embedded Binariesはフレームワークをプロジェクト内に直下インポートし、Linked Frameworks and Librariesはプロジェクト内にFrameworksグループを自動作成しリンクを管理しています。

プロジェクト内の階層が広まると見づらくなる為、手動でFrameworksグループを作成し、Embedded Binaries管理もLinked Frameworks and Libraries管理も混ぜてしまおうと思いました。

複数フレームワークの管理経験がない為、混ぜてしまっても良いか分からない状態です。
ご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

フレームワーク導入の参考サイト
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/NaN

以上よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: フレームワークの物理的な場所はどこにあっても問題ありませんので、ディレクトリに分けて整理しても適当でも好みの問題です。ただプロジェクトのディレクトリの外にはしない方がいいです。というのは、その場合プロジェクトディレクトリを移動したら参照が切れてしまうことがあるからです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！非常に助かりました。